# git-lfs is giving me a "locking API" error when I try to push to the server

Tags: ssh, git

I am trying to enable `git lfs` on my server but it's not working.

The server is already hosting git repositories which is working fine.

The server is runnign Debian bookworm.

What I did on the server:

```
$ git lfs install
Git LFS initialized.
$ mkdir test_repo
$ cd test_repo
$ git init --bare
```

What I did client side:

```
$ git clone ssh://<...>:/<path..>/test_repo
$ cd test_repo
$ echo "hello world" > file.txt
$ git lfs track *.*
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Now when I push:

```
$ git push origin master
Remote "origin" does not support the Git LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.<unknown>.locksverify false
batch request: missing protocol: "<unknown>"/s
```

There seems to be a problem with the "locking API".

How can I fix this ?

I already tried disabling the "locking API" but can't figure out how exactly.

Comment: It doesn't work with an SSH-based clone. https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1044 "Git LFS doesn't support SSH as a transport protocol."

Comment: @ceejayoz this seems to be an old post. I heard that the v3 of git lfs *does* support ssh now. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.